# Search and copy multiple folder by file list

Tags: batch-file

I have a list of names of folders in a txt file and I want to do a search in a folder that should work this way: if the name of the folder (which is written in the txt file) is in the path, then copy that folder and all its content (files and subdirectories) in the folder `C:\okcopied`

Example general folder content:

- folder 1
- folder 2
- folder 3
- folder 4
- folder 5

Sample file.txt:

- folder 1
- folder 3

End result log folder:

- folder 1, subdirectories and files was copied
- folder 3, subdirectories and files was copied

How can I do? I tried with:
`for /D %t in (C:\test\file.txt) do copy %t c:\okcopied` but that doesn't work. This command copies the file "file.txt" to the `C:\okcopied` folder.

Comment: so the copy worked for the file but not the folder?

Comment: My command copy only the file "file.txt" in C:\okcopied :(
I want copy, for example, folder 1 IF folder 1 is list in file.txt. If exist, then copy folder 1 to C:\okcopied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("c:\test\file.txt"
) do if exist ".\%%a\" robocopy ".\%%a" "c:\okcopied\%%a" * /e
```

Comment: I don't know if you are male or female, but i love u! You saved my ass! thank you very much